# How to find out the heroku version from bash in windows 10

Tags: bash, heroku

After installing heroku CLI in my system (Winsows 10), when I try to find the version,I am getting a message saying "bash: heroku: command not found"

Comment: Did you add it to your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually add a symlink to fix the installation directory,
which might be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/bin/heroku
```